# Adding description to layer package via arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers

I am trying to add description to layer and then make a layer package of multiple files at once. Everything works just fine, but the formatting of description is just wrong.

I want to add new lines after each line. What i tried is adding \n, \r \n, '\n', '\r \n', \u000d, 
.

None of these are working.I simply ran out of ideas. In help there is nothing about the formatting.

```
files = arcpy.ListRasters()

name = "Hazard Index"

description = "Hazard Index  \
   \
   Ranges of depths for different level of hazard \
   \
   Depth (d)\
   \
   not flooded     No Hazard    0"                                             


for file in files:
   raster_layer = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management (file, file[:-4])

   #raster_layer.name = file[:-4]
   arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(raster_layer, layer)

   lyr = arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management (raster_layer, output + file[:-4] + ".lyr")

   raster_lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(str(lyr))

   raster_lyr.description = description
   raster_lyr.name = file[:-4]

   arcpy.PackageLayer_management(raster_lyr, output + file[:-4], "PRESERVE", "", "", "", "", "", "", summary, tags)
   print "Package created for: " + file
   os.remove(str(lyr))
```

result is (I did not copy all of the text here, but you get the idea)

[image: result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes the best way to find how to do something is to see how ArcMap does it.

I added a raster layer to my map, and set a Description in the layer properties

[image]

I then used arcpy to show me that description (using ArcMap's built-in Python window).  Note I did *not* use `print`, as that won't show the escape characters.

```
>>> raster_lyr.description
u'This is a\r\nraster layer\r\ndescription'
```

As you can see from the result, to force a new line in the layer description you need to use a combination of `\r` and `\n`

Therefore, in your code to force those new lines you can enter the following:

```
description = "Hazard Index\r\n\r\nRanges of depths for different level of hazard \r\n\r\nDepth (d)\r\n\r\nnot flooded No Hazard 0"

raster_lyr.description = description
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I guess I just put a space between \r\n, because I used something similar. Thank you very much.